# URL with only slashes in pure php like codeigniter uri pattern

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an application which creates stores for users and they can create a single page store using my dashboard.The final URL generated after they create the store is as follows

```
baseurl/store/{username}/{random number}
```

Now how can I access the {username} and {random number}.

If I have a index file in directory 'store'
--store
----index.php will I be able to fetch the above username and random number from the url?If this was in codeingiter things would have been easy , and I could make a controller with name store and get the uri segments.But how can I do the same in pure PHP without any frame work.Please do help

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `.htaccess` in order to do that.

So create this file at the root of your project directory (where `index.php` is).

**.htaccess** content :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?username=$1&rand=$2
```

**index.php** content:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

Now try using an url like : `mywebsite.com/store/jack_97/354` and you should end up with a dump of `$_GET` telling you that this array contains two keys : "username" and "rand"