# display paging in php URL

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

is there any way to change my paging  in the url from view.php?page=1  to view.php/page/1 this is my code to generate  paging  I don't care about security cause it works localy

```
$rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * from table"));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);

if($page>1)
{
echo "<a href='?page=".($page-1)."' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a>";
}
if($page!=$total)
{
echo "<a href='?page=".($page+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a>";
}

echo "<ul class='page'>";
for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
{
if($i==$page) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li>"; }

else { echo "<li><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: You have one possible answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045545/url-with-only-slashes-in-pure-php-like-codeigniter-uri-pattern).

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework on the `php` side? If so, please add that to your question - or see the answer mentioned before by Milan.